# Error al compilar proyecto en CORDOVA

Tags: android, cordova

Obtengo este error al compilar mi proyecto, estoy usando CORDOVA:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   >     non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: Note: Some input files use or
>     override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for
>     details. java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>     com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>     java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main :
>     Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main :
>     Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>     java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main :
>     Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) Exception in thread "main"
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>     Exception in thread "main"
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>     Exception in thread "main"
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>     Exception in thread "main"
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   >     non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Soy nueva en cordova necesito ayuda porque no comienza mi compilación de proyecto, muchas gracias!

Comment: Este mensaje de error te lo da con un proyecto vacio?

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta el contenido de tu build.gradle!

Comment: si estoy arracando apenas el proyecto, es decir lo que queria era compilar y ver si el emulador funcionaba y me da este error que coloque, soy nueva con esto y de verdad no tengo idea porque este error tan grande.

Answer (score 0):

Es importante que agregues el contenido de tu archivo `build.gradle` para revisar tu configuración.

Si nos basamos en el error:

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException

Te sugiero agregar el soporte multidex en tu archivo `build.gradle`.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {          
        // habilita soporte multidex.
        multiDexEnabled true
    ...
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```